# What does the error "no viable alternative at input” in my import function for Soley Studio mean?

Tags: graph, nodes, data-visualization, graph-databases, import-from-excel

I want to import a list of nodes using *ImportTypedNodeList* function. But when I check for errors or build the Solution it gives me this error:

> no viable alternative at input '('

And

> mismatched character '.' expecting set null

This is my import function:

```
sequence ImportFunctions{

ImportTypedNodeList( "..\..\Data\ProdArchitecture.xlsx" , 2, 2, -1, -1, "Functions", "", "ProdFunction" )

}
```

Is the path to my file wrong? The file is added to Data folder in my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a minor adjustment to the path you provide. Instead of `..\..\` use `..\\..\\`. Then Soley Studio can process the path and will look for the folder and file relatively to the solution/project path.

In your case the import sequence will look like this:

```
sequence ImportFunctions{ 
ImportTypedNodeList( "..\\..\\Data\\ProdArchitecture.xlsx" , 2, 2, -1, -1, "Functions", "", "ProdFunction" )
}
```

Also check out the Soley Studio Help Center to find out more about import functions: [Help Center - Data Import](https://support.soley.io/article-categories/import-data-studio/)